# Post method in swift with server user and password

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, alamofire

I'm trying to convert this curl command (*which works*):

```
curl https://address --user appID:appPassword -d grant_type=client_credentials -d scope=read -d format=json
```

to a swift one.

I already have that, but I don't know how to pass my appID and appPassword:

```
private func LoadKey() {
    let params : Parameters = ["grant_type":"client_credentials",
                                       "scope":"read",
                                       "format":"json"]

    let url =  "https://address"

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).response{ response in

          print(response)

    }

}
```

Have a good day, and thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the Data first as `dictionary`, use `.updateValue()`  function then parse them back to params,

```
var params : [String:String] = ["grant_type":"password",
                                "scope":"read",
                                "format":"json"]

params.updateValue("myPassword", forKey: "grant_type")
```

If the key is not found it will create a new key with that value.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my post, the param `grant_type` is not `password` but `client_credentials`. And in your answer I don't know where I put the `appId`.